# What is the best way to emulate imaginary constexpr_assert in C++17?

Tags: c++, c++17, assert, constexpr, static-assert

I just watched cppcon [talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vA5sdxbwUG8) where author of the frozen library explains how he uses assert in constexpr functions and it works(because at runtime it works as it should, and at compile time it triggers non constexpr execution of a function so compiler error happens).

Problem with this is that you can not give meaningful text error to the user like with static_assert and compilation fails in the implementation of assert macro.

Also you can not use static_assert on function arguments since they are not constexpr and I do not want to move function arguments inside <> to make them constexpr. This is the example of the transformation I want to avoid:

```
constexpr unsigned int safe_right_shift(const unsigned int val, const unsigned shift){
    assert(shift<sizeof(unsigned int)*CHAR_BIT); //ugly error
    return val >>shift;
}

template<unsigned int shift>
constexpr unsigned int safe_right_shift_t(const unsigned int val){
    static_assert(shift<sizeof(unsigned int)*CHAR_BIT);
    return val >>shift;
}
```

Is there a better way in C++17 to do what hypothetical constexpr_assert would do?

I define constexpr_assert as an assert that only checks values during constexpr evaluation(aka compile time).

P.S.
error:

> note: non-constexpr function '__assert_fail' cannot be used in a constant expression

[full code](https://wandbox.org/permlink/maSTKO5siPdT7god)

Comment: Could you use `assert("shift amount must be less than the bitsize of the value" && shift<sizeof(unsigned int)*CHAR_BIT);`? It doesn't give you the values of the parameters, but I'm not aware of a way to string-ify those parameters and report them in the error message.

Comment: I suppose C++20 contracts would work, but in C++17... I tried doing [something like this](https://godbolt.org/z/xz6PPf) and abusing SFINAE in general but I didn't get any result...

Comment: [`std::is_constant_evaluated`](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/p0595r1.html) could prove very helpful here.